# Deleting tags attracting off-topic questions

Tags: discussion

This question has become moot, as I have just removed the tags (in accordance with the current 3:0 vote). I will accept an answer ASAP, which seems to be tomorrow.

---

I noticed that the [Edgeworth-box](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edgeworth-box) tag usually attracts basic homework questions. Since it is an elementary illustrative tool things are unlikely to be different in the future.

All on-topic questions should be covered by general-equilibrium or Pareto-optimality.

Should we remove this tag from the 13 tagged questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the tag should be removed.

Comment: Moderators: Is there a way to do this automatically? Since it is only 13 questions, we can also do it manually.

Comment: The general consensus at meta seems to be that we should delete the tag from every question that has it. The system will then automatically remove the tag after 24h. Alternatively, we could create a synonym that automatically remaps Edgeworth-box into general equilibrium; but that would allow people to continue typing Edgeworth-box into the tag field.

Comment: Would the mapping solution still cause Google to forward people googling 'Edgeworth-box' to our site? To the tagged questions?

Comment: From reading the following meta post, it seems like not having Edgeworth-box as a tag might be a little damaging to our Google performance on  that keyword because Stack Exchange automatically incorporates tags into HTML titles for the purpose of search engine optimisation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184273/tags-appear-in-lowercase-in-google-search-results-should-they-be-capitalized

Answer (score 0):

No, the tag should not be removed.